# Cross validation - how many samples?

Tags: cross-validation

I'm not a statistics guy but want to investigate a problem like this:

I have a number (hundreds) of trends that I wish to use to come up with an average trend. My method was to be by using the average value of the individual trend at each time step, to come up with the average, then fit this new average trend with a smoothed line.

From this original set of hundreds, I then wish to take a subset of the original and an average of those the same way, fit a smoothed trend to this average and compare the resulting trend to the original and repeat that procedure. I think this method is "Repeated random sub-sampling validation" ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_%28statistics%29#Repeated_random_sub-sampling_validation)).

My questions are:

- is there a rule (of thumb?) as to how many sub-samples I should take
  from the original (i.e. how many times should I repeat the process)
- how large this sub-sample group should be in relation to the original
  group (how may trends from the original to include in the smaller
  subsets)?

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Have you tried http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_size_determination